# Two Apache Passengers listeners using the same Rails app in the same host/computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, camping

I have a Rails app that is served by Apache and Passenger, using only SSL.

Now, I have an external connection that must be made using only HTTP.

As I'm only listening for port 443 for this Rails App, I don't check in the code if the connection is secure or not.

Every connection for port 80 for this App are redirected to the https 443.

The question is, can I have two Apache Passengers listeners using the same Rails app in the same host/computer ?

One for 80 and antoher one for 443, of course each one will listen for different url.

I think this is not possible, at least my initial tests weren't successful.

What are the best options to accomplish this ?

- Add a new Rails App instance, with a different name (wasting resources but easier one!!!!)
- Add one instance of Camping with Passenger for just this purpose, listening to special address and just for one route
- ...

thanks,

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, finally solved using a 'descafeinatted Rails apps' with the minimum minimum for just this purpose ... maybe wasting resources but the server where it is at this moment is capable, maybe we can improve in the future but at least this has been the less painful workaround ...